# Migrate samba domain to Active directory

Tags: windows, active-directory, samba

i have a Samba3 domain and i want to migrate to Active Directory (W2k8 or 2012 server).

How can i achieve that?

I read that ADMT tool can do that, but didn't find any feedback.

I also read that we can upgrade from Samba3 to Samba4, then join the Windows Server to the Samba4 domain as a Domain Controller, and then remove the Samba4 server, but i can't do this because it's actually running on custom Samba domain (Sambaedu3).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't sound like Samba3 has the ability to act as a domain controller.  Could you perhaps migrate (not upgrade) from sambaedu3 to samba4 and then migrate to AD?